# having issues with negative number changing to 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im making my first unity project, a copy of flappy bird. when making the code to despawn the pipes after they go out of frame i have an issue. i use a variable called deadZone=-46, but when i run the game this variable changes to one, why is that?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PipeMovement : MonoBehaviour{
    public float moveSpeed = 1;
    public float deadZone = -46;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        transform.position += (Vector3.left * moveSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
        if (transform.position.x < deadZone){
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure its not 1 in your inspector?

Comment: Where do you see that the variable changes to 1? In the debug log? Or inspector?

Comment: @BugFinder  yes thats where it changes to one and i dont understand why

Comment: your code is correct. There must be some other component that changed that value. Or maybe you have made changes to a prefab and your scene does actually use a different version of your script?

Comment: have you added a debugger watch with that assigns the value instead of comparing it, like "deadZone=1" instead of "deadZone==1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're using unity you would be much better off using a box collider to fit the size of the frame, using math is very unreliable and difficult for what you're trying to do.

Though seeing as you said it's your first project you might not know what means so I would advise looking up "collider on trigger enter and trigger exit". Though you're probably using/going to use similar methods for gameover functions anyway.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html

Like the camera object typically has a tag called "MainCamera" so if you know how to put a collider on that object you can mark the collider as a trigger and make it the same size as the camera frame. And in the code you can use a the method void ontriggerexit() and put code in there to check if "other"(the detected collider) has the tag of camera and then destroy the pipe object.